# javascript:document.location.href does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use js functions to improvise navigation in my website, although I am not able to parse the function in  using document.function.href. I have simplified my code here for clarity. Please help me.

```
<button href="javascript:document.location.href=destinationFunc("target.html");">PRESS</button>
```

Comment: `"target.html"` --> `'target.html'`

Comment: since nobody explicitly said what the problem is: you used double quote as your `href=".."` string delimiter, and then also used double quotes to wrap your `"target.html"` value. This confuses the browser and makes it think your `href` value cuts off at your next double quote.  To solve for this, you can instead wrap your inner string value in single quotes as shown in commented answer above, or you can escape your inner double quotes, e.g. `href="some\"foo\"thing"`

Comment: The `button` element does not have an `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Ivar, that worked. Thank you Crayon for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="var lnk='target.html'; document.location.href=destinationFunc(lnk);">PRESS</button>
```

Comment: There is no need to create a variable. And a good answer should also explain *why* these changes are necessary ;)